# How can display console.log() in text editor as a comment line?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, text-editor, vscode-extensions, console.log

Simply I want to see console.log() values in under of that line as a comment line .

like this:

```
var five=5
console.log(`The number is ${five}`)
//The number is 5
```

I saw this method in a video tutorial .But I did not care so much about that thing or extension .Now looking console.log() values in browser is so annoying and taking my time.

is anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: 1. Do you know what a comment is?
2. What tutorial are you talking about?
3. Visual Studio Code also has an integrated terminal in which you can see console.log statements.
  DEFINITION OF COMMENT: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/concept-of-comments-in-computer-programming/

Comment: Just open the terminal in VSCode, and run `node file.js`

Comment: "Simply I want to see console.log() values in under of that line as a comment line" - What do you mean? The JavaScript compiler (or interpreter in some cases) ignores comments completely.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't remember that tutorial and Of Course i know what are comments in javascript :)

Comment: how would you find out which line to modify when something is logged.

Comment: Here you are guys .This extension does exactly what I wanted (https://quokkajs.com/)

Comment: @samarmohan I have also seen a plugin in a video, that will automatically show and update the value the expression or function in the right side as a comment instead of going to browser or terminal , just for development purpose. example if you want to see output of `3**2` you will see the result on right side as a comment. and it gets updated as the expression or code is changed in realtime, although I am not sure if the comment will be there in the file once saved.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are guys .This extension does exactly what I wanted [Quokka.js](https://quokkajs.com/)
And found one more great extension called Wallaby

Answer (score 2):

I dont get your question but to debug I use an extension in VS code and I can see the values of variables: VS Code - Debugger for Chrome

Comment: I have also seen a plugin in a video, that will automatically show and update the value the expression or function in the right side as a comment, just for development purpose.